# Scrolling Effect for Drupal Website

Tags: php, jquery, css, drupal, drupal-7

I have came across a website recently that has this effect when you scroll down, the individual blocks of text will move in accordingly, and when you scroll back up, the individual blocks of text will move out accordingly as well. The website is: http://aperia.com.sg/ for reference.

I am pretty new to the website (Drupal) field, and this effect made me super curious, I have Google-ed for 2 days on how to do this effect, but can't seem to find any similarity to this effect or how to do it.

I have used this add on module which can be found at: https://www.drupal.org/project/parallax, but it seems to lead to this error, "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error...." Its most likely to be server host problem right? But is there a work around if the server host admin is unwilling to comply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be Parallax. Try this, for example, https://www.drupal.org/project/parallax

Comment: Yup, it is the name I am looking for... Upvoted your answer. Thanks, however, implementation of that leads to this error "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error.." You have any idea why?